# Python appending empty list

Tags: python, for-loop

I am very new to Python and trying to learn by trial-and-error, so my question may sound naive for the community.

Let's say I have two empty lists with only the first element defined:

```
a = [[]]*20
a[0] = 0
b = [[]]*20
b[0] = 1
```

I want to use a for loop for creating the other elements of the lists:

```
x = 20
for i in range(1,x):
    a[i] = b[i-1],
    b[i] = a[i-1]+b[i-1]
```

What I obtain is the following error:`TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple`.
Basically I am trying to reproduce the fibonacci series (a famous starting point in Python tutorial), but I would like to experiment other ways of obtaining the same output.

Thank you!

Comment: You have an extraneous comma at the end of the first line of the loop, which turns it into a tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
a[i] = b[i-1],
```

Notice the comma at the end? That makes python think you're dealing in [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Remove it and the error will be gone.